# What does whisper mean in "Our Future Whispers Like a Gust of Wind"?

Tags: translation, interpretation

> "Our Future **Whispers** Like a Gust of Wind" ⌈english cover | Sepia Pro.⌋【Liella!】

In the [title of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Me85pcgPx1c), *whisper* is used here. This title is translated from a Japanese anime song's name *未来は風のように*

Here's a words list for the Japanese words above what I mentioned.

- 未来 => Future
- は => (am, is, are)
- 風 => Wind
- (の)ように => Like, similar

---

In the original language, there is no **whisper** meaning here, How do I understand **whisper** in the translated sentence?

Following definition is copied from Cambridge Dictionary

> noun: a way of speaking very quietly, using the breath but not the voice, so that only the person close to you can hear you:
>
> - *I heard whispers outside my room.*
> - *She said it in a whisper so I presumed it wasn't common knowledge. "You see," she said, lowering her voice to a whisper, "he hasn't been well recently."*

it doesn't make sense for me, especially "Future Whispers"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking what the connection might possibly be between the sound of a whisper and the sound of wind?

Comment: It's a very old song cliché that the wind 'whispers'. _Every little breeze seems to whisper 'Louise'_

Comment: When I read the words *Our Future Whispers Like a Gust of Wind* I instantly assume they're ***translated*** from some other language (or really bad native Anglophone poetry). It's just not the kind of language native Anglophones normally use. So basically, the cited text "means" whatever the Japanese original means (or whatever any given native speaker *thinks* it means, which will vary from person to person).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning of translated text, where the actual original is available for scrutiny

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Or ['loser'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_paG_Irk_e4).

Comment: It's common when translating song lyrics to add words to fit the tune, meter, or rhyme. I think you're confused because "whispers" is a verb not a noun here, and you quote the noun definition.

Comment: The meaning of "whisper" in the translated text is "speak very softly using one's breath".  This is an example of *personification* in which a non-human thing ("the future") is figuratively described with human characteristics (such as the ability to whisper).

Answer (score 1):

If you Google the Japanese characters you get a [Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%AF%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB) in Japanese which you can then have translated into English.
The title of the page (Mirai wa Kaze no Yo ni), in English is

> The future is like the wind

This ties in with your word list. It appears to also be the title of an Anime series.
It looks as if whoever wrote the English title to the YouTube video,

> Our Future Whispers Like a Gust of Wind

use a bit of poetic licence. In other words it's not a word-for-word translation but something of a similar meaning they thought sounded good in English.
As Michael Harvey says in his comment, in English we have the saying that *the wind whispers* which, quite possibly, doesn't exist in Japanese and hence the "better" translation.

Comment: I think it's written by someone who doesn't know exactly what **gust** means.

Comment: @TimR I never said it was a native English speaker who titled the YouTube video

Comment: Peter- that makes the question even more off-topic and unanswerable.

Comment: @PeterJennings I never said you said it was a native speaker. :-)